# Correct way to do multiple calls to same service API using Spring Reactive WebClient?

Tags: spring, mono, spring-webflux, flux, reactive

What is the correct way to do multiple calls to the same service API? The below code is how I am trying to achieve.

```
Flux.fromIterable(userIds)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .flatMap(this::getUser)
```

Comment: Just using a flatMap i belive

Comment: Yes. I read about it at multiple places and understand that flatmap is enough. But can you explain the use case where I can use parallelFlux and what is the disadvantage of using it instead of just flatmap operator. @ThomasAndolf

Answer (score 1):

This is to my understanding from reading the docs, but i could very well be wrong, in such case, downvote and i'll remove this answer.

Documentation about `parallel`:

> dividing data on a number of 'rails' matching the number of CPU cores, in a round-robin fashion.

`Flux#parallel` will return a `ParallelFlux` that will portion out any work on a number of so called `rails` that *will* distribute the workload in a round-robin fashion over the number of cores the computer has. **You are guaranteed that the work is placed on multiple computer cores.**

Documentation about flatmap:

> Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers, then flatten these inner publishers into a single Flux through merging, which allow them to interleave.

While `flatMap` (and here i could be wrong) is just making the work asynchronous by placing all items in individual `Mono<T>` and the designated threads will switch between the workloads trying to perform the workload and resolve the `Mono<T>`s as fast as possible using the designated threads in the defined scheduler. **Here there seems to be no guarantee that multiple cores will be used.**

This is my understanding from reading the documentation.

[Parallelizing Work with ParallelFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux)

[Flux#parallel](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel--)

[Flux#FlatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

My personal opinion is that it is probably overkill to designate its own core for each request, there is probably some setup time to assign the jobs to cores etc. etc.

I would only use parallel for CPU intensive work, while regular `flatMap` will work fine for `blocking` tasks where the threads can just easily just switch to other work when waiting for a response.